# jquery accordion open/close

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a jquery accordion with special functionality. In 99% of cases it functions just as it should. I have a use case where I need to open the top/first accordion on page load while maintaining the functionality (in this case plus/minus with corresponding state open or close using font-awesome).

I can get the accordion to open by hard coding class "open" and "display: block;". By doing so, it screws up my font awesome state.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/chasedano/yar3ah29/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="accordion-container">
  <a class="accordion-toggle" href="#"><span class="toggle-head"><h2 class="t-h2">Web Ready Lorem Ipsum</h2>

    </span><span class="toggle-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></a>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>The images below provide examples of safe sleep environments that follow the safe sleep strategies explained in Safe to Sleep<sup>®</sup> materials.</p>
    <p>These low-resolution images are available for your convenience. If you choose to use the images, you are agreeing to: </p>
    <ul class="sts-bullet">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Duis malesuada purus sit amet tellus semper tempus.</li>
      <li>Etiam iaculis est ac erat mollis, vitae vulputate ante sagittis.</li>
      <li>Mauris interdum nulla interdum libero hendrerit interdum.</li>
      <li>Cras aliquet arcu vitae mattis congue.Cras aliquet arcu vitae mattis congue.</li>
      <li>Vivamus bibendum arcu vel enim luctus, eu dignissim erat efficitur.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-container">
  <a class="accordion-toggle" href="#"><span class="toggle-head"><h2 class="t-h2">Web-Ready Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 2</h2>

    </span><span class="toggle-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></a>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>The images below provide examples of safe sleep environments that follow the safe sleep strategies explained in Safe to Sleep<sup>®</sup> materials.</p>
    <p>These low-resolution images are available for your convenience. If you choose to use the images, you are agreeing to: </p>
    <ul class="sts-bullet">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Duis malesuada purus sit amet tellus semper tempus.</li>
      <li>Etiam iaculis est ac erat mollis, vitae vulputate ante sagittis.</li>
      <li>Mauris interdum nulla interdum libero hendrerit interdum.</li>
      <li>Cras aliquet arcu vitae mattis congue.Cras aliquet arcu vitae mattis congue.</li>
      <li>Vivamus bibendum arcu vel enim luctus, eu dignissim erat efficitur.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-container">
  <a class="accordion-toggle" href="#"><span class="toggle-head"><h2 class="t-h2">Web-Ready Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text 3</h2>

    </span><span class="toggle-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></a>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>The images below provide examples of safe sleep environments that follow the safe sleep strategies explained in Safe to Sleep<sup>®</sup> materials.</p>
    <p>These low-resolution images are available for your convenience. If you choose to use the images, you are agreeing to: </p>
    <ul class="sts-bullet">
      <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
      <li>Duis malesuada purus sit amet tellus semper tempus.</li>
      <li>Etiam iaculis est ac erat mollis, vitae vulputate ante sagittis.</li>
      <li>Mauris interdum nulla interdum libero hendrerit interdum.</li>
      <li>Cras aliquet arcu vitae mattis congue.Cras aliquet arcu vitae mattis congue.</li>
      <li>Vivamus bibendum arcu vel enim luctus, eu dignissim erat efficitur.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
/*ACCORDION*/
.accordion-container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1em;
    /*clear: both;*/
}

.toggle-head {
    display: block;
    max-width: 95%;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.accordion-toggle {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: 400;
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #000 !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.accordion-toggle.open {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    color: #fff;
}

.accordion-toggle:hover {
    background: #E8E8E8;
}

.accordion-toggle span.toggle-icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: .5em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: #65308a;
    top: .5em;
}

.accordion-content {
    display: none;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // create accordion variables
    var accordion = $(this);
    var accordionContent = accordion.next('.accordion-content');
    var accordionToggleIcon = $(this).children('.toggle-icon');

    // toggle accordion link open class
    accordion.toggleClass("open");
    // toggle accordion content
    accordionContent.slideToggle(250);

    // change plus/minus icon
    if (accordion.hasClass("open")) {
      accordionToggleIcon.html("<i class='fa fa-minus'></i>");
    } else {
      accordionToggleIcon.html("<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>");
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: If the accordion is this: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion it opens the first tab onload by default

Comment: I'm using a "customized" version where a user can open and close at will. If you look at the js fiddle you will see what I mean.

Comment: I realize this is unique, but I'm stuck at this point with modifying a single use case out of multiple implementations.

Comment: Hey @DanStump, I looked the Fiddle over found an error about $jQ not properly loading for Bootstrap. I removed the old jQuery js 1.11.2  file and then used an updated it with jq 2.2.1 it looks like it works good. Sorry almost forgot the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/f8c34agq/

Comment: much appreciated! I am using different version live but for the fiddle I'm using cdn's.

Comment: As my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow I am humbled. I broke a lot of "rules" apparently but hope to come back for more. I really appreciate everyone's input on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force the click so you can reuse your function. Add an id to the accordion you want to open...

```
  <a class="accordion-toggle" id="ac1" .... > </a>
```

Then at the end of the script, add

```
$('#ac1').click();
```

You can also trigger a click with trigger() method. Using trigger() instead of click() will eliminate ambiguous calls.

```
$('#ac1').trigger('click');
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I had tried various versions of this and failed. I'm not fluent in javascript obviously.

Comment: You are welcome! If my answer helped, please mark it as correct :)

Comment: New to stack overflow. How do I mark this as the answer or can I?

Comment: That's a good trick (no problem with that), but I recommend to use `trigger()` method since `click()` is ambiguous (`click()` method can be a trigger or a listener), so it's better to write `$('#ac1').trigger('click');` to make it bulletproof. My upvote to this answer

Comment: I agree with you marcos. Thanks, i just modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just trigger click on the first element:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var toggles = $('.accordion-toggle')
      toggles.on('click', function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();
           // create accordion variables
           var accordion = $(this);
           var accordionContent = accordion.next('.accordion-content');
           //// ...............

      });
      // Fire click! /////////////////
      toggles.first().trigger('click');
      /////////////////////////////////
   });
```

Comment: Thanks, very succinct and logical. Much appreciated!

Comment: This is most bulletproof than the accepted answer, my upvote to you

Answer (score 0):

[image]>

> class="toggle-head">Web Ready Lorem Ipsum -

name all the elements that are going to be effected as shown above and then do this at the end of the

```
$("#oLink").addClass("open"); // link name
$("#oLinkDiv").show(); //div name you want to show
$("#oLinkSpan").html(''); //span that you want to change to - sign
$("#oLinkSpan").html('<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>'); //chaging sing to minus
```

$(document).ready(function() {

check the image for details of your fiddle

[image: complete image of page]